# Remove vertical space in gather enviroment

Tags: beamer, block, gather

I have the following code in a beamer:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{New frame}
\begin{block}{Distorsión radial}
\begin{gather*}
\delta_{ur}(u,v)=u(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4),\\
\delta_{vr}(u,v)=v(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4). 
\end{gather*}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

That's how it looks like:
[image]

How could I remove that vertical space?

List of packages:

```
\usepackage{natbib}        
\usepackage{url}           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{numprint}      

\usepackage{amsmath}       
\usepackage{mathrsfs}      
\usepackage{amssymb}       
\usepackage{amsfonts}      

\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{friendly}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}  

\usepackage{tikz}     

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Theme used: Warsaw

Comment: *which* vertical space are you concerned about -- the space between the rows of displaymath material, or the space between the title and the first row of displaymath material?

Comment: Could you please post a compilable code?

Comment: @Mico, the space btw the first equation and the tittle of the block.

Comment: @SergioCavero - You need to provide (a lot) more information, then. E.g., which beamer "theme(s)" do you employ? How did you change the font setup relative to the default?

Comment: @Bernard there you have. I just add the frame enviroment.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not a complete compilable code.

Comment: Contrary to the claim you make in the comment to @Bernard, you have *not* yet provided sufficient information to let readers of your your posting replicate the screenshot you posted. Without this information, how do you expect people to come up with a diagnosis, let alone a solution?

Comment: My project has more thant 6 files of configurations. This may be the reaseon: 
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=green,innerrightmargin=30pt,innerleftmargin=30pt,
backgroundcolor=black!5,
skipabove=10pt,skipbelow=10pt,roundcorner=5pt,
splitbottomskip=6pt,splittopskip=12pt]
}{%
\end{mdframed}
}

Comment: We're not asking for *all* configuration-related information, but just for what's needed to replicate the screenshot you posted. For sure, it's crucial to know (a) how you modified the font-related defaults and (b) which theme(s) you chose.

Comment: Please, have a look know? do you need something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility: the `\useshortskip` command from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{New frame}
    \begin{block}{Distorsión radial}\useshortskip
    \begin{gather*}
    \delta_{ur}(u,v)=u(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4),\\
    \delta_{vr}(u,v)=v(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4).
    \end{gather*}
    \end{block}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A math display environment should never be used at the start of a paragraph, because it would add an empty line.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{New frame}
\begin{block}{Distorsión radial}
\centering

$\begin{aligned}
\delta_{ur}(u,v)&=u(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4),\\
\delta_{vr}(u,v)&=v(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4). 
\end{aligned}$

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here `aligned` is better than `gathered`.

[image]

Of course, you could remove the space generated by the empty line:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{New frame}
\begin{block}{Distorsión radial}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{align*}
\delta_{ur}(u,v)&=u(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4),\\
\delta_{vr}(u,v)&=v(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4).
\end{align*}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

I actually see a *missing* space!

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{New frame}
\begin{block}{Distorsión radial}

\begin{align*}
\delta_{ur}(u,v)&=u(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4),\\
\delta_{vr}(u,v)&=v(k_1\cdot r^2+k_2\cdot r^4). 
\end{align*}
\mbox{}

\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works for me! Even it is not the answer I will use that. Many thanks

Comment: @SergioCavero I added the trick for `align` or `gather`. Actually, in your picture I see a *missing* space.